# Unable to Persist RDD in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created RDD from List but when I try to Persist that RDD , It Throws error stating

> Expression of type RDD[foo] is not conform to expected type rdd.type

My code is

```
class foo (x : Int) extends Serializable  {
val random = new Random()
var hori      : Array[Double]       =   Array.fill(x)(math.random)
var vert      : Array[Double]       =   Array.fill(x)(math.random)
}

val list = List.fill(100)(new foo(10))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(list, 5)  // 5 partitions
var rdd1 = rdd.persist() // This RDD is var as have to update it 

rdd1 = rdd1.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(x,y) =>
//Here this code throws above mentioned error 
//update  
 y
}
```

How can I get rid of this error ?

Comment: scala or pyspark? - cannot have both as tags

Comment: Not that easy to follow all this, some wires crossed here I believe, pls be clearer and show what does actually work

Comment: @thebluephantom this is actual problem. When you compile this code same error code will be there.

Comment: There are many issues - try working in the Spark shell firstly as a way of prototyping.

Comment: Can you please show the content of your 'mapPartitionsWithIndex' block?

Comment: @thebluephantom  issue was fixed by following trick

     val rdd = sc.parallelize(list, 5)  
     var rdd1 = rdd
     rdd1.persist()